# When/how does font initialization occur? Changes at init time seem to only have partial effect

Tags: fonts

I have been experimenting with variable-pitch for some buffers. I have the following snippet in my emacs init:

```
(set-face-attribute 'variable-pitch nil
                    :family "Bookman Old Style"
                    :height 180)
```

If I start emacs and run the following in my `*scratch*` buffer:

```
(assoc :height (face-all-attributes 'variable-pitch))
```

I get:

```
(:height . 180)
```

So far, so good. But `M-x describe-face variable-pitch` shows:

```
           Height: (lambda (base) (truncate (* (face-attribute (quote fixed-pitch) :height nil (quote default)) 1.23)))
```

And, indeed, the size in buffers seems to be a bit "too large".

If I run `set-face-attribute` again, the 180 value "sticks". Where/how should I be doing this initialization so it works initially?

Comment: [Startup is complicated](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html#Startup-Summary), and those 30 steps don't even include all the details about startup on various GUI platforms. How are you starting Emacs: daemon or not? What version, on what operating system, and how did you obtain the Emacs program (some of the details of font initialization can depend on compile-time options)?